# How to find a folder path in mac os x using python?

Tags: python, macos

I am new to Mac OS X (10.10.4). I want to write a code by using python 2.7, which first I have to check if a folder "Pictures" exists, and follow by saving a file into it. However, I dunno the folder path.

```
 folder = "~/usr/my_name/Pictures"
```

However, after I run

```
path.exists(folder)
```

The result is false.

What should is the path I should set to folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` character signifying the home directory is a *shell* convention, and doesn't just work outright in Python.

Use the [`os.path.expanduser()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to have it interpreted like the shell would:

```
import os.path

folder = os.path.expanduser("~/usr/my_name/Pictures")
```

Comment: I get NameError: name 'os' is not defined.  At the beginning of my program, i call "from os import path", is that enough?

Comment: @pill45: then simply use `path.expanduser`; you imported the `os.path` module as the `path` name in your code. I assumed the more common `import os.path` was used.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is helpful, but it is not working on my code. I am not sure what is going on, I think I will post a new question for that.